# Is there a lock which allows multiple threads access until a thread requests exclusive access

Tags: c#, synchronization

I have a chat connection class which once connected with the `Connect` method is able to send messages with the `SendMessage` method. Once the user is done they call `Disconnect`.

I want a lock which allows an unlimited number of `SendMessage` operations to take the lock, but only allows the `Connect`/`Disconnect` operatons to begin once they have an exclusive lock and all other `SendMessage`/`Connect`/`Disconnect` operations have exited and released the lock.

With this type of lock I could ensure the `SendMessage` has safe access to the internal `Socket`, `SocketReader` and `SocketWriter` classes and can be sure none of them will be disposed by a parallel `Disconnect` call.

It also has the benefit of queuing up all `Connect`/`Disconnect`, which obviously cannot run simultaneously.

Does such a lock exist in the .NET framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the ReaderWriterLock will allow one write and multiple reads to occur simultaniously? This means my Disconnect method (Write lock) would clash with the SendMessage method (read lock), and therefore this type of lock is not suitable.

Comment: @NoPyGod No, it will allow *either* one writer *or* multiple readers, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a `ReaderWriterLock` or better `ReaderWriterLockSlim` in .Net 4. To use SendMessage you would obtain a reader lock but calling `Connect` or `Disconnect` would require the writer lock.

Comment: As I said to the other guy -- Correct me if I'm wrong, but the ReaderWriterLock will allow one write and multiple reads to occur simultaniously? This means my Disconnect method (Write lock) would clash with the SendMessage method (read lock), and therefore this type of lock is not suitable

Comment: @NoPyGod a writer cannot enter until all readers have exited.

Comment: There is also an upgradeable reader lock which will allow other readers to enter but can be upgraded to a write lock later, at which point the thread blocks until all readers exit.